# hide/show toggle divs

Tags: jquery, html, hide, toggle, show

Please help! I've been trying to figure out how to close a particular DIV when it is already open.

For example, please view: http://jsfiddle.net/WGRvw/

If I click on **BC** the DIV should appear but if I click on it again, the DIV should disappear but I can't figure out how to make it disappear. Also, I only want one DIV to appear at a time.

I tried doing an else:

> ```
>           $(function(){
>             $(document).ready(function () {
>                 $(".prov").click(function(){
>                     $(".clearfix").hide();
>                 });
> ```

```
                $('#BC').hide();
                $('#BC-show').click(function () {
                    if( $('#BC').toggle('slow')) {
                        return false;

                    }
                    else {
                        $('#BC').hide();
                    }
                });
                $('#AB').hide();
                $('#AB-show').click(function () {
                    if($('#AB').toggle('slow')) {
                        return false;

                    }
                    else {
                        $('#AB').hide();
                    }
                });
                });
            });

    });
```

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/WGRvw/141/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be attaching two events to each element.

One using **className** 
Another using **ID**

Try this code

```
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#BC, #AB').hide();

        $(".prov").click(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[0];
            $('.clearfix').not('#'+id).hide();
            $('#' + id).toggle('slow');
            return false;
        });
    });
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/WGRvw/150/)**

Just attach the event using the class and get the id from it and use it to toggle.

Comment: Thanks!

This works properly... However, I only want one div to appear at a time.

Comment: sure.. If thats the case add this in your code.. $('.clearfix').not('#'+id).hide(); .. Check updated code

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you click the show links is that the divs get hidden and than you call toggle which basically shows the div again each time. Therefor the desired effect doesnt show.
So just leave out the following:

**Update**:

```
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#BC, #AB').hide();
                $('#BC-show').click(function () {
                    $('.clearfix:visible').not('#BC').hide()
                        $('#BC').toggle('slow');
                        return false;
                });
                $('#AB-show').click(function () {
                    $('.clearfix:visible').not('#AB').hide()
                        $('#AB').toggle('slow');
                        return false;
                });
            });
```

Comment: Thanks!

This works properly however if I remove 

            $(".prov").click(function(){
                $(".clearfix").hide();
            });

Multiple divs will appear.. I only want one div to appear at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I appears that your first event handler is hiding the element, and then toggle is being called. Thus, toggle shows the element, since   `$(".prov").click(function(){ $(".clearfix").hide();  });` is hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#BC, #AB').hide();

    $('.prov').click(function() {
        $('#'+this.id.replace('-show','')).toggle('slow').siblings('div').hide('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WGRvw/151/)

There's no need for two DOM ready functions, and the first function bound to the class hides the elements, and the second function bound to the ID toggles the elements, which by now are of course hidden, and will always be shown.

Comment: Thanks. However, I only want one div to appear at a time.